# VSC java cache behaviour in test when reading file

Tags: java, testing, caching

So i've noticed if a have a test that reads a file.

I run the test, it fails because of some error with the file.

I correct the file and run the test again. The test still fails.

I make some adjustments to the code for example sout("hello world") the test passes. Why is this? does VSC store files in memory when running tests and still uses an old version of the file when rerunning the test?